# Need help pulling the information correctly BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

evr_begin = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
evr_end = (datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=1)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

url = "https://mms.kcbs.us/members/evr_search_ol_json.php?" \
      f"otype=TEXT&evr_map_type=2&org_id=KCBA&evr_begin={evr_begin}&evr_end=. 
      {evr_end}&" \ "evr_radius=50&evr_type=269&evr_region_type=1"
response = requests.request("GET", url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='lxml')

for event in soup.find_all('div', class_='row'):
    kcbs_competition = event.find('b').getText()
    kcbs_comp_date = event.find('i').getText()
    print(kcbs_competition, kcbs_comp_date)

for info in soup.find_all('div',class_='col-md-4'):
        print(info.find('a').getText())
```

Here is the link to the website https://mms.kcbs.us/members/evr_search.php?org_id=KCBA
I'm am trying to pull everything under the name and date.

Comment: What *exactly* is your question or issue? See [ask]

Comment: my 2nd for loop is not performing correctly. For example if you go to the link i want to print        Frisco, CO 80443
UNITED STATES
STATE CHAMPIONSHIP
Reps: BUNNY TUTTLE, RICH TUTTLE, MICHAEL WINTER
Prize Money: $13,050.00.      for each competition

Comment: try looking at response.text directly to see if the info you want is included.  if it's not, then its being loaded dynamically after the GET request is complete.  then instead of bs, you will have to use Selenium, which actually opens the site in a browser.

Comment: the text I want does appear in response.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desired data just using the API url. An example is given below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import datetime

url = 'https://mms.kcbs.us/members/evr_search_ol_json.php?otype=TEXT&evr_map_type=2&org_id=KCBA&evr_begin=6/15/2022&evr_end=7/15/2022&evr_address=&evr_radius=50&evr_type=269&evr_openings=0&evr_region=&evr_region_type=1&evr_judge=0&evr_keyword=&evr_rep_name='
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='lxml')

item=[x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select('div.col-md-4:nth-child(1)')]
print(item)


item2=[x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select('div.col-md-4:nth-child(2)')]
print(item2)
```

**Output:**

```
 ['Frisco BBQ Challenge6/16/2022 - 6/18/2022Frisco, CO 80443UNITED STATES', 'York County BBQ Festival6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022Delta, PA 17314UNITED STATES', 'Central Plains Ribfest6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022Holdrege, NE 68949UNITED STATES', 'Knights Of Columbus BBQ Smoke Off "4 Life"6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022Kansas City, KS 66106UNITED STATES', 'Rose Festival 21st Annual KCBS BBQ Contest6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022State Center, IA 50247UNITED STATES', 'Hoosier BBQ Classic Day 16/17/2022 - 6/18/2022Franklin, IN 46131UNITED STATES', 'Hoosier BBQ Classic (One Meat Ribs)6/17/2022 - 6/17/2022Franklin, IN 46131UNITED STATES', 'Almost Heaven BBQ Bash6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022Roanoke, 
WV 26447UNITED STATES', 'Central Plains Ribfest (Steak)6/17/2022 - 6/17/2022Holdrege, NE 68949UNITED STATES', 'Clay County Juneteenth BBQ Contest (One Meat Ribs)6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022Liberty, MO 64068UNITED STATES', 'BBQ Battle Finland (POSTPONED)6/18/2022 - 6/19/2022Tampere,  33840FINLAND', 'The War of Barbeque6/18/2022 - 6/19/2022Isola della Scala (VR),  300257ITALY', 'Hoosier BBQ Classic Day 26/18/2022 - 6/19/2022Franklin, IN 46131UNITED STATES', 'The War of Barbeque (ONE MEAT RIBS)6/18/2022 - 6/18/2022Isola della Scala (VR),  300257ITALY', 'Columbia Valley Smokeshow6/24/2022 - 6/26/2022Invermere,  V0A1K0CANADA', 'The Cache Smokeout at the American West Heritage Center (POSTPONED UNTIL 2023)6/24/2022 - 6/25/2022Logan, UT 84321UNITED STATES', 'Big BBQ Bash6/24/2022 - 6/25/2022Maryville, TN 37804UNITED STATES', 'Heritage Days BBQ Showdown (Day One)6/24/2022 - 6/25/2022Belvidere, IL 61008UNITED STATES', 'The Great Lenexa BBQ Battle - Kansas State Championship6/24/2022 - 6/25/2022Lenexa, KS 66227UNITED STATES', 'Miles City Cowtown Cookoff6/24/2022 - 6/25/2022Miles City, MT 59301UNITED STATES', 'Lake Murvaul BBQ Cook-Off6/24/2022 - 6/26/2022Carthage, TX 75633UNITED STATES', 'Smokin Deltana BBQ Challenge (POSTPONED)6/24/2022 - 6/25/2022Delta Junction, AK 99737UNITED STATES', 'Riverland Smokers BBQ Contest6/25/2022 - 6/26/20226669 MH Dodewaard,NETHERLANDS', 'Second Annual Central Maine BBQ Cookoff6/25/2022 - 6/26/2022Skowhegan, ME 04976UNITED STATES', 'Heritage Days BBQ Showdown (Day 
Two)6/25/2022 - 6/26/2022Belvidere, IL 61008UNITED STATES', 'Giant National Capital Barbecue Battle6/25/2022 - 6/26/2022Washington , DC 20006UNITED STATES', 'Central Maine BBQ Cook Off (ONE MEAT RIBS)6/25/2022 - 6/25/2022Skowhegan, ME 04976UNITED STATES', "Lowell's Smokin' In the Ozarks-Arkansas State Challenge7/1/2022 - 7/2/2022Lowell, AR 72745UNITED STATES", 'Happy Basset 2nd Annual BBQ Competition7/1/2022 - 7/2/2022Topeka, KS 66609UNITED STATES', '2nd Annual VFW 
Post 3396 Armed Forces BBQ Challenge (MASTERS)7/1/2022 - 7/2/2022Sparks, NV 89431UNITED STATES', 'The Art of BBQ7/1/2022 - 7/2/2022Sterling, CO 80751UNITED STATES', 'Twin Smoke7/2/2022 - 7/3/2022Vilnius,  LT 14200LITHUANIA', 'Sweet Home Icebox Cookoff 20227/2/2022 - 7/3/2022Sweet Home, OR 97386UNITED STATES', '2nd Annual VFW Post 3396 Armed Forces BBQ Challenge (ONE MEAT RIBS)7/2/2022 - 7/2/2022Sparks, NV 89431UNITED STATES', 'Smokin with Weemala (One Meat Chicken)7/2/2022 - 7/2/2022Carmel ,  6076AUSTRALIA', 'Smokin with Weemala (One Meat Ribs)7/2/2022 - 7/2/2022Carmel,  6076AUSTRALIA', 'South Carolina Festival of Discovery7/7/2022 - 7/9/2022Greenwood, SC 29648UNITED STATES', 'Ohio Veterans BBQ Cook-Off (CANCELLED)7/8/2022 - 7/9/2022Kettering, OH 45440UNITED STATES', 'Clayton BBQ Cook-off7/8/2022 - 7/9/2022Clayton, CA 94517UNITED STATES', 'Sand Creek Summer Daze Saucy & Glazed BBQ Competition7/8/2022 - 7/9/2022Newton, KS 67114UNITED STATES', 'Harvest on Fire at the Winery7/8/2022 - 7/9/2022Marshall, IL 62441UNITED STATES', '2022 Black Silos Swine in the Vine BBQ Contest (Day 1)7/8/2022 - 7/9/2022Trenton, MO 64683UNITED STATES', '2022 Black Silos Swine in the Vine BBQ Contest (Day 2)7/9/2022 - 7/10/2022Trenton, MO 64683UNITED STATES', 'New Jersey State Barbecue Championship7/9/2022 - 7/10/2022North Wildwood, NJ 08260UNITED STATES', 'Chillin & Grillin in the Glades7/15/2022 - 7/16/2022Wise, VA 24293UNITED STATES', 'KTD Smokin Gobbler Cook-off7/15/2022 - 7/16/2022Worthington, MN 56187UNITED STATES', 'KTD Smokin Gobbler Cook-off (One Meat Ribs)7/15/2022 - 7/16/2022Worthington, MN 56187UNITED STATES', 'Bordertown BBQ Brawl7/15/2022 - 7/16/2022Sault Ste Marie, MI 49774UNITED STATES', 'Bordertown BBQ Brawl (One Meat Ribs)7/15/2022 - 7/15/2022Sault Ste Marie, MI 49774UNITED STATES', 'Central Illinois BBQ Throwdown7/15/2022 - 7/16/2022Eureka, IL 61530UNITED STATES', 'Central Illinois BBQ Throwdown (One Meat Ribs)7/15/2022 - 7/15/2022Eureka, IL 61530UNITED STATES', '2022 Cameron Elks BBQ Cook Off (Day 1)7/15/2022 - 7/16/2022Cameron, MO 64429UNITED STATES']
['STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: BUNNY TUTTLE, RICH TUTTLE, MICHAEL WINTERPrize Money: $13,050.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: ANGELA MCKEE, ROBERT MCKEE, LOUISE WEIDNERPrize Money: $5,500.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: LARRY VOTH, LYNDA VOTHPrize Money: $10,000.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: FORREST BRUCE, LARRY HADLEYPrize Money: $5,000.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: CLARA WILLIAMS, 
JONATHAN B WILLIAMSPrize Money: $7,000.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: BECKY DRUETZLER, DAVE DRUETZLERPrize Money: $7,500.00', 'Reps: BECKY DRUETZLER, DAVE DRUETZLER', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: JULIE COOK, RUSTY COOKPrize Money: $13,000.00', 'Reps: LARRY VOTH, LYNDA VOTHPrize Money: $1,500.00', 'Reps: ROSEMARY MORROWPrize Money: $1,350.00', 'Reps: ANGELA FISHLOCK, MARK FISHLOCK', 'Reps: HAYMO GUTWENIGER, LUCA FAMIGLI', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: BECKY DRUETZLER, DAVE DRUETZLERPrize Money: $7,500.00', 'Reps: HAYMO GUTWENIGER, LUCA FAMIGLI', 'Reps: BRENDA BLACK, KEN BLACKPrize Money: $4,750.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: STEVEN FLEWALLEN, BRIAN MOORE', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: CONNIE AMIDEI, JONATHAN AMIDEIPrize Money: $10,000.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: CHARLIE BRINZA, JEANNE TITUSPrize Money: $11,100.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: FORREST 
BRUCE, LARRY HADLEY, DAVE ROGERS, PEG ROGERSPrize Money: $13,300.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: MICHAEL SANTIAGO, RHONDA SANTIAGOPrize Money: $9,450.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: BOB MCKINNON, TERRI MCKINNON', 'Reps: BUNNY TUTTLE, RICH TUTTLE', 'Reps: MARIANNE VAN GALEN, MAYCO VAN GALENPrize Money: $1,800.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: DOUG REID, ALAN ROTHROCKPrize Money: $10,000.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: CHARLIE BRINZA, JEANNE TITUSPrize Money: $11,100.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: ALEX JR BROWN, BILL JONESPrize Money: $14,400.00', 'Reps: DOUG REID, ALAN 
ROTHROCK', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: KAREN JANE WILLIAMS, RALPH WILLIAMSPrize Money: $15,000.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: CLARA WILLIAMS, JONATHAN B WILLIAMSPrize Money: $3,800.00', 'Reps: MICHAEL SANTIAGO, RHONDA SANTIAGOPrize Money: $6,000.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: MICHAEL WINTER, BRIAN MOOREPrize Money: $8,000.00', 'Reps: ANGELA FISHLOCK, MARK FISHLOCK', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: JULIE POE, IAN SCHMIDTPrize Money: $25,000.00', 'Reps: MICHAEL SANTIAGO, RHONDA SANTIAGOPrize Money: $500.00', 'Reps: KARINA RUMENS, ROB STEVENS', 'Reps: KARINA RUMENS, ROB STEVENS', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: JULIE COOK, RUSTY COOK, CAROLYN WELLS, DOUG REID, MIKE GARRETSONPrize Money: $19,850.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: SCOTT GRINSTEAD, STEVE GRINSTEAD', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: JULIE POE, IAN SCHMIDTPrize Money: $8,975.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: LARRY VOTH, LYNDA VOTH', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: BECKY DRUETZLER, DAVE DRUETZLERPrize Money: $3,070.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: ROSEMARY MORROW, FORREST BRUCE', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: FORREST BRUCE, ROSEMARY MORROW', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: JEFF CHAMBERS, REGINA BODNAR, LOUISE 
WEIDNERPrize Money: $8,800.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: ALEX JR BROWN, BILL JONES', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: JOHN SCHARFFBILLIG, JEANNE TITUS', 'Reps: JOHN SCHARFFBILLIG, JEANNE TITUS', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: BECKY DRUETZLER, DAVE DRUETZLERPrize Money: $6,500.00', 'Reps: BECKY DRUETZLER, DAVE DRUETZLERPrize Money: $600.00', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: DAVE ROGERS, PEG ROGERS', 'Reps: DAVE ROGERS, PEG ROGERS', 'STATE CHAMPIONSHIPReps: DONNA YOUNG, ED YOUNG']
```

Comment: I understand this but how would I place each thing into a separate list?

Comment: @ClayH I've updated